# What to do on a bogus/scammer site?

Tags: web-development, security

We just found out that one of our client's website has a bogus site. The domain name is somewhat similar to our client's name, only matter of word is the difference. What alarms us is this bogus site use the real business address of our client, and the About page content is somewhat similar to the original. Doing a simple WHOIS also shows the Registrant, Administrative and Technical seems to be exactly the same too. Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: Please define what you mean by a Bogus site? Please also include details of the domain type, the content is it near duplication? etc. Provide more information otherwise the question will be closed. thx.

Answer (score 1):

I got your question and the only way to resolve your issue is reporting Google about this problem.

http://support.google.com/bin/static.py?hl=en-gb&ts=1114905&page=ts.cs&&rd=1

Go through this page and select 'Web search' in the first question and again choose "A page appearing in Google’s search results is violating my company’s trademark rights" in the next question

This may be the only solution for your problem.